# Knockout binding attribute via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

Can I do something like

```
var friendss="<div id='two' data-theme='a' class='ui-content'>
<ul id='tust' 
data-role='listview'>
<li><a href='#'><img data-bind='attr:{src: friend.img}' alt='Friend'><p data-bind='text:
 friend.name'></p>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>";
```

And then

```
$("#tust").attr("data-bind","foreach:{data:friends(), as:'friend'}");
```

Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is, appending html to body via js and then inserting data-bind attribute also via js( after dom with above html has been populated)
If not, how can I achieve the above i.e. inserting data-bind via javascript.
Thanks

Comment: why do you want to add data-bind later? If you are already getting a populated data from the server and if it is not going to change, what is the point adding data-bind for knockout bindings?

Comment: @SujeshArukil I'm basically developing a single page application(SPA) and for that I want to be able to do all the above via js

Comment: Are you rolling your own SPA? Or planning to use a framework like Durandal? If you are rolling your own SPA, your templates should have the data-bind attributes already set and not added later. Use requirejs text plugin to pull in your template files and use ko.applyBindings to bind it to your appropriate viewmodels.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, will look into them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the template-binding. E.g. define the template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="myTemplate">
    <div id="two" data-theme="a" class="ui-content">
        <ul id="tust" data-bind="foreach: {data: friends, as: 'friend'}" data-role="listview">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img data-bind="attr: {src: friend.img}" alt="Friend">

                    <p data-bind="text: friend.name"></p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

Then the actual binding:

```
<div id="random123" data-bind="template: {name: 'myTemplate', data: {friends: friends()}}"></div>
```

if you need to dynamically add that, just bind the DOM-element.

```
ko.applyBindings(theMVVM, $("#random123")[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped, selected as answer